# Converting a .rptproj from VS2005 to VS2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, reporting-services

I've got my brand new VS2008 and decided to convert my main solution from VS2005. One of the projects is a SQL2005 reporting services project. Now that I've converted I cannot load it in VS2008. Is there anyway around this?

My problem is that my solution is a hybrid and has websites libraries and reports in there.
Separating it out breaks the logic the solution entity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual Studio 2008 does not support the 2005 business intelligence projects, so if you have not done so already don't uninstall 2005 Business Intelligence! You can continue to maintain those projects independently in VS2005.

SQL Server 2008 Business Intelligence will integrate with VS2008 so you will require that and an upgrade to your existing reporting project to use in VS2008.

Answer (score 1):

To obtain BI2008 you must install MSSQL2008. When you have done so, you may find the project will load. If it doesn't, create a new report project and add existing RDL files to it.